# How to get the index of a String after the first space in vbsript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to grab the first characters before a space.

I know it can be done this way

```
 str = "3 Hello World"
 str = Mid(str, 1,2)
```

But how would i do this after a space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: Looks like you changed your question to get characters *BEFORE* the first space instead of *AFTER*. I've updated my examples.

Here's one way:

```
strTextBeforeFirstSpace = Split(str, " ")(0)
```

Assuming a space exists in your string, this would return everything up until the first space.

Another way would be:

```
strTextBeforeFirstSpace = Left(str, InStr(str, " ") - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of the first space with the InStr function

```
InStr(str, " ")
```

And use this as a parameter in your Mid function

```
Dim str, index
str = "3 Hello World"
index = InStr(str," ")

'only neccessary if there is a space
If index > 0 Then
   str = Mid(str,1,index - 1)
End If
```

Comment: it returned everything after and including the first space. I',m hoping to get the characters before the first space

Comment: If you want everything AFTER the space add 1. If you want everything before, use it as the length parameter instead. What exactly are you trying to do? Your question was "How to get the index of a String after the first space in vbsript" --> InStr(str, " ") + 1 would do exactly that

Comment: I'll extend my answer to cover that